# how to mock this this method with jmock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmock

I would write some unit test for some class which use DAO:

```
class UserDao{
    public void saveToDb(Entity e){
        e.setId(1234);
    }
}


class UserService{
UserDao userDao;
public void someMethod(){
Entity e = new Entity();
assertTrue（e.getId() == 0);
userDao.saveToDb(e);
assertTrue(e.getId()>0);
}
}
```

I would write unit test for UserService.someMethod which use UserDao.I want to use jmock to create a MockUserDao.

Comment: I'm not clear, do you want a unit test for saveToDb method itself or for something else?

Comment: i want a unit test for a method which call saveToDb.

Comment: Ok, mocking out a class is easy enough but there's no point me just pasting from the manual as I assume you've read them. What have you tried so far or what do you not understand that is causing you problems?